# Is there any way for a discord bot to send messages as a user who typed a command?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot in python (using discord.py) which can type a message when a user enters a command (in my case !spam). Here is the code I have put together.

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, leng, tim,*,msg):
    import time
    leng = int(leng); tim = int(tim)
    if leng > 10 :
        await ctx.send('Please do not spam too much. The limit is 10 messages.')
    else:
        for i in range(leng) :
            await ctx.send(msg)
            time.sleep(tim)
```

Does anyone know of any code which I can put in which can make to bot type a message as the user which used the command? (So it will look like the user typed the message instead of the bot).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make it look like a user sent a message is via a webhook. It will have their profile picture and name but it will still have the BOT tag next to it.

```py
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, leng: int, tim: int,*,msg):
    # Checking if a webhook exists already
    webhook = discord.utils.get(await ctx.channel.webhooks(), name='Spammer')
    if webhook is None:
        # If the webhook didn't exist, we create one
        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name='Spammer')
    if leng > 10 :
        await ctx.send('Please do not spam too much. The limit is 10 messages.')
    else:
        for i in range(leng) :
            await webhook.send(content=msg, username=ctx.author.display_name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await asyncio.sleep(tim)
```

Also, I went ahead and changed a few things to make your code a little more efficient. Firstly I used the type hints in your command's def line, when you do this discord.py will automatically convert them [as described here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#basic-converters). I also changed `time.sleep` to `asyncio.sleep` to avoid blocking [as described in the discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean), make sure to import `asyncio` at the top.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me. However, When I try and use the !spam command an error pops up which says: 'method' object is not iterable for the line webhook = discord.utils.get(ctx.chhanel.webhooks, name = 'Spammer'). Do you know why this error is occurring and any way to fix it?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, is there any way to remove the BOT tag from the user? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah that's my bad, I had forgotten that `webooks` was not an attribute and instead was a coroutine (async function that needs to be awaited), I have edited my answer to reflect the correction. In regards to your second comment, it is not possible to remove the bot tag no, that's as close as you will be able to get to sending a message as a user.